# Spring declarative transaction semantics by method name of subclasses

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-aop

I'm trying to implement different transaction semantics based on method name in a Spring Boot application. As far as I can tell I have to do this via the XML as shown [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/transaction.html). That's not ideal, but fine.

The problem I have is matching all public methods on subclasses of my BaseService. I've seen examples of this with the full AspectJ but in the Spring aop: stuff it doesn't seem to work.

```
<aop:config>
    <aop:pointcut id="services" expression="execution(public ppi.nestup.v3.service.BaseService+.*(..))"/>

    <aop:advisor advice-ref="txAdvice" pointcut-ref="services"/>
</aop:config>
```

It doesn't like the aop:pointcut expression. The error is

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Pointcut is not well-formed: expecting 'name pattern' at character position 51 
execution(public ppi.nestup.v3.service.BaseService+.*(..)
```

If there's a way to do this via annotations or Java config that would be better, but I'm not sure how to wire into the Spring transaction support with AspectJ pointcuts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you read an AspectJ tutorial or the [Spring AOP manual](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#aop) in order to learn the syntax.

- The problem with the pointcut in your question is that you are not specifying a return type for the methods you want to intercept.
- The problem with the second is that now your are trying to match all public methods returning(!) a `BaseService` instance.

What you probably really want is

```java
execution(public * ppi.nestup.v3.service.BaseService+.*(..))
```

And BTW, you do not need to use XML configuration, you can declare your aspects in annotation style via `@Aspect`, `@Pointcut`, `@Before`, `@Around` or  so, too.

Comment: I understand you can build your own AspectJ pointcut  and around advice, but there's no examples of hooking them into Spring's declarative transaction management like there is with the XML.

Answer (score 0):

This was a typo. It should have been:

```
<aop:pointcut id="services" expression="execution(public ppi.nestup.v3.service.BaseService+ *(..))"/>
```

But it still doesn't seem to be matching any methods